# Arrow keys seem stuck after water damage

Tags: keyboard, water-damage

A few days ago i spilled water on my laptop. I got it fixed and it works fine except for the fact that my arrow up and arrow left key seem stuck sometimes. This always happens when I use one of the letters from the top row and sometimes at random. I already tried disableing them using sharpkeys35. Currently all mmy arrow keys and the page up button are disabled, however if I press down q for example the stripe that tells you where you're typing shoots upwards.

Is there a way to fix this easily? I don't care if my arrow keys get disabled permanently. 
Thanks for reading this

Comment: Take it to a professional - see this for a rather harsh version of what not to do - http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/219097/85275 [Mac/PC/phone irrelevant]

Answer (score -1):

After spilling water in your keyboard and you are experiencing issues, either water is still present and is causing a fault, or there is permanent damage. The first thing to do is to make sure your machine is completely dry. Power it down. If you are comfortable, open it up and remove the keyboard from the case.  The best thing you can do is put all the parts inside a sealed plastic bag with some uncooked rice. The rice will absorb any residual moisture. If you find it's still wet inside, take a dry, lint free cloth and gently dab up the water. Place the laptop under a fan to help low away any moisture for a few hours.

If you are still experiencing issues, there may be permanent damage. You can try ordering a replacement keyboard from the manufacturer.